# Simple Sequence Generation?

Tags: c#, linq, sequence

I'm looking for an ultra-easy way to generate a list of numbers, 1-200.
(it can be a List, Array, Enumerable... I don't really care about the specific type)

Apparently .Net 4.0 has a [Sequence.Range(min,max)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336752.aspx) method. 
But I'm currently on .Net 3.5.

Here is a sample usage, of what I'm after, shown with Sequence.Range.

```
public void ShowOutput(Sequence.Range(1,200));
```

For the moment, I need consequitive numbers 1-200.  In future iterations, I may need arbitrary lists of numbers, so I'm trying to keep the design flexible.

Perhaps there is a good LINQ solution?  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

.NET 3,5 has `Range` too. It's actually [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).ASPX) and returns `IEnumerable<int>`.

The page you linked to is very much out of date - it's talking about 3 as a "future version" and the `Enumerable` static class was called `Sequence` at one point prior to release.

If you wanted to implement it yourself in C# 2 or later, it's easy - here's one:

```
IEnumerable<int> Range(int count)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < count; n++)
        yield return n;
}
```

You can easily write other methods that further filter lists:

```
IEnumerable<int> Double(IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    foreach (int n in source)
        yield return n * 2;
}
```

But as you have 3.5, you can use the extension methods in `System.Linq.Enumerable` to do this:

```
var evens = Enumerable.Range(0, someLimit).Select(n => n * 2);
```

Comment: You are indeed correct.  I didn't read closely enough.  Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: Actually, you implementation isn't correct. `Enumerable.Range()` is in the form `Range(int start, int count)`, so your second parameter should be '`count`' and your stop condition should be `n < start + count`.

Comment: That's true. I've changed the example to be slightly different anyway (always starting from zero), as you could then use `Select` to add an offset to each item - an example of orthogonality.

Answer (score 6):

```
var r = Enumerable.Range( 1, 200 );
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [System.Linq.Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx).

Regarding the second part of your question, what do you mean by "arbitrary lists"? If you can define a function from an `int` to the new values, you can use the result of Range with other LINQ methods:

```
var squares = from i in Enumerable.Range(1, 200)
              select i * i;
```